# Understanding the proof of Scott's core theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am having some trouble understanding the proof of Scott's core theorem as presented by Rubinstein and Swarup ([link, requires academic access](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/22/5/495/440111?redirectedFrom=PDF)).

Scott's core theorem states the following: if $M$ is a topological $3$-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group, then any compact, incompressible, $3$-submanifold $K$ is contained in a core $K'$ of $M$. By *incompressible* we mean that the frontier $\overline{K} \cap \overline{M - K}$ contains no nontrivial loops that contract trivially in $M$. By *core* we mean that the inclusion of $K'$ into $M$ induces an isomorphism of their fundamental groups.

In Rubinstein/Swarup, they first prove the theorem in the special case that the frontier of $K$ has finitely many components, and that the fundamental group of each component of $K$ is indecomposable and not infinite cyclic. They then use this special case to prove the **relative core theorem**, which they then use to prove the general case. The proof of the relative core theorem is where I am getting confused.

**THEOREM (relative core theorem):** If $M$ is a $3$-manifold with finitely generated fundamental group, then any compact submanifold of the boundary $C \subset \partial M$ is contained in a core of $M$ whose intersection with the boundary is $C$.

For the moment, let's assume that $C$ is connected and incompressible. If I understand this case, it will be easy to generalize. To prove the relative core theorem, they consider small annular collars $A_i$ in $C$ around each component of $\partial C$. They then let $T$ be a topological torus with a hole cut out, and glue $T \times [0, 1]$ to each annulus $A_i$ along the hole. The resulting space $C'$ looks like $C$ with a thickened torus sprouting off of each boundary component $\partial C$. The claim is that by the special case of Scott's core theorem, this space $C'$ is contained in a core of $M'$, which is the manifold $M$ together with the glued tori.

I am having trouble understanding why the special case of the core theorem applies. $C'$ is compact, its frontier has finitely many components (in fact a single component, which is homeomorphic to $C$), but I do not see why its fundamental group is **indecomposable and not infinite cyclic.** If $C$ is simply connected, for example, then I would think that $C'$ should be homeomorphic to a thickened torus, which has decomposable fundamental group $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}.$ In fact, I can't see why we should glue tori at all instead of gluing spherical caps; if I glued hemispheres to each annulus, I would think $C'$ should always be homeomorphic to a thickened $S^2$, which has trivial fundamental group and thus satisfies the special case of the core theorem.

These are my two chief confusions:
(i) Why should the surface obtained by gluing tori to $C$ have an indecomposable, not-infinite-cyclic fundamental group?
(ii) What is the point of gluing tori? Why not just glue hemispheres?

Any help?

EDIT: I have attached the following image of definitions from the relevant paper in response to some comments.

[image]

Comment: Your statement of the theorem has some flaws: you seem to be conflating $K$ with the core that contains it.

Comment: Your definition of a compact core is incorrect. The usual condition is that $\partial K$ is incompressible in $cl(M-K)$, not in $M$. Just think about the case when $M$ is an open handelbody.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for the correction, I accidentally used variables redundantly; I have corrected this by calling the core K'.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not claiming that the boundary of the core is incompressible; the statement of the theorem is that any compact set with incompressible frontier is contained in a core.

Comment: OK, then your definition of an incompressible submanifold $K$ is wrong. I am sure this is not what Rubinstein and Swarup wrote in the paper. As I said, think about a handlebody: How many incompressible (in your sense) submanifolds $K$ does it contain?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I'm not sure what to tell you. This appears to be the definition in their paper, which I've included as a screenshot. The empty set always satisfies the conditions I listed, so I don't see a problem with the core theorem.

Comment: This is Swarup, one of the authors.Just noticed this. Since it is from an year ago,it is possible that it is clarified by now. If not, please let me know at anandaswarupg@gmail.com
I have retired 15 years ago and it may take some time to get access to the papers.